# what is the output of (socket.getInputStream().read(byte []))?

Tags: java, sockets, http

I'm pretty new in java and this is my code.
I want to write a simple java socket explorer 
that you enter "host" and "path" and it will send http request for that host then will store the html file or picture or etc in your computer.
The problem is that the socket receive http response but the program  cant save any thing.program make the file but the file is empty.
I know that this is the problem of the bottom line but i don't know the solution?
while ((a=s.getInputStream().read(inputline)) != -1)
any help please

```
public class explorer {

    private static Socket s;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String host ="google.com";
            String path ="/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
            s = new Socket(host, 80);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            pw.println("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1");
            pw.println("Host:"+host);
            pw.println("");
            pw.flush();
            String[] parts = path.split("/");
            String filename = parts[parts.length-1];
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            byte [] inputline =new byte[2000];
            byte [] inputline2 =new byte[300000];
            int a=0;
            int resultlenght=0;
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/mahmoud/Desktop/"+filename);
            while ((a=s.getInputStream().read(inputline)) != -1)
                    {
                        System.arraycopy(inputline,0, inputline2,resultlenght,a);
                        resultlenght+=a;
            }
            for(a=0;;a++)
            {
                if(inputline2[a]==13 && inputline2[a+1]==10 && inputline2[a+2]==13 && inputline2[a+3]==10)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            byte [] inputline3 =new byte[300000];
            System.arraycopy(inputline2, a+4, inputline3, 0, inputline2.length-a-4);

            fos.write(inputline3,0,inputline3.length);
            fos.flush();

            fos.close();
            in.close();
                }
            catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: "+e);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception: "+ex);
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`read(byte[] b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-) returns

> the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

Until `-1` is returned, the number of bytes read from the `InputStream` is copied to the buffer `b`.

Comment: really thanks 
so why when i run the code, it stops on that line and
 do not change the value of variable a to -1